# Subquotients of abelian varieties with good reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

> Let $B$ be an abelian variety over a DVR with good reduction, and let $A$
>   be a subquotient of $B$. Then $A$ has good reduction.

I know a proof of this statement using Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich. Is there a more direct argument (e.g. not mentioning Galois action)?

Comment: Serre and Tate write that this corollary was known to Koizumi and Shimura. I have been unable to obtain the article, but it is indexed by MathSciNet: [MR116017](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=116017). (The review strongly suggests it is a direct argument, and there certainly does not appear to be mention of Galois actions.)

Comment: The Koizumi/Shimura paper can be found in Shimura's Collected Works. They show that if there is a surjective homomorphism from A to B and A has good reduction, then so does B. It was written in 1959 before most people knew  of schemes and such questions were difficult. It looks geometric and direct, but makes unpleasant reading today. A modern version must be possible.

Comment: I see an easy argument in equicharacteristic zero, but I’m blanking in mixed characteristic. (In equichar zero: suffices to prove the statements for quotients and subs separately, but then enough to prove for subs by duality. For subs, take the closure of the generic fiber of your subscheme; this is a gp scheme hence smooth by the char zero assumption.)

Comment: @DanielLitt: The normalisation of the closure of the generic fibre probably works in general.

Comment: BLR use Neron models. The challenge is to find a direct proof not using Neron models. K&S did, so we should be able to.

Comment: @ulrich: Of course I agree (in fact it's probably true w/out normalization), I just don't see a proof the special fiber is smooth in positive characteristic.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: @user126532: I don't think this question or this user is of the same nature as those that you are referencing.

Comment: @DanielLitt: The special fibre will not be reduced in general--it is easy to make examples--which is why one needs to normalize.

Comment: @ulrich: would you mind making an example? Of course I agree this is possible in the case of general G in H, but I don’t see how to do it in the case under consideration (I.e. G is an Abelian scheme over a dvr and H is an Abelian subscheme of the general fiber).

Comment: @DanielLitt: See 2) on p. 132 of this paper https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1513797226 for how to construct such examples.

Comment: @ulrich: Thanks -- are these examples the closures of their own generic fiber? It's not clear to me...

Comment: @DanielLitt: yes, since they are flat over the base.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: Ah great, thanks!